# Change Last Writing Date using date in file name

Tags: powershell

I would like to change the Last writing date of several CSV files using the dates contained in the names of the different files

---

**Example :**
Input : File_20221210085032.CSV (LastWriteTime = 25 October 2022 16:54:25)
Output :(LastWriteTime = 10 December 2022 08:50:32)

---

In that extent i wrote a code based on my knowledge and some help from internet, this code should do what i want to achieve however i get some errors and i cannot find the errors.

Please find below my code :

```
cls
$Foldober = 'D:\Bob\Test'



$DateFormat = "yyyymmddhhmmss"


$FileList = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $Folder -Filter '*.csv' -File
foreach ($FL_Item in $FileList) {


    $Null = $FL_Item.BaseName -match '_\d{14}'
    $DateString = $Matches.DateString
    $date_from_file = [datetime]::ParseExact($DateString, $DateFormat, $Null)

    $FL_Item.CreationTime = $date_from_file
    $FL_Item.LastWriteTime = $date_from_file
    $FL_Item.LastAccessTime = $date_from_file

    # show the resulting datetime info
    '=' * 20
    $CurrentFileInfo = Get-Item -LiteralPath $FL_Item.FullName
    $CurrentFileInfo.FullName
    $CurrentFileInfo.CreationTime
    $CurrentFileInfo.LastWriteTime
    $CurrentFileInfo.LastAccessTime
    }
```

I get the following error

```
Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
At C:\Users\Bob\Desktop\Script\test.ps1:15 char:5
+     $date_from_file = [datetime]::ParseExact($DateString, $DateFormat ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatException
```

Update #2

After having got ridden of $null in the ParsExact as suggested i get the following errors :

```
cls
$Foldober = 'D:\Bob\Test'



$DateFormat = "yyyymmddhhmmss"


$FileList = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $Folder -Filter '*.csv' -File
foreach ($FL_Item in $FileList) {


    $Null = $FL_Item.BaseName -match '_\d{14}'
    $DateString = $Matches.DateString
    $date_from_file = [datetime]::ParseExact($DateString, $DateFormat)

    $FL_Item.CreationTime = $date_from_file
    $FL_Item.LastWriteTime = $date_from_file
    $FL_Item.LastAccessTime = $date_from_file

    # show the resulting datetime info
    '=' * 20
    $CurrentFileInfo = Get-Item -LiteralPath $FL_Item.FullName
    $CurrentFileInfo.FullName
    $CurrentFileInfo.CreationTime
    $CurrentFileInfo.LastWriteTime
    $CurrentFileInfo.LastAccessTime
    }
```

```
    Cannot find an overload for "ParseExact" and the argument count: "2".
At C:\Users\Bob\Desktop\Script\test.ps1:15 char:5
+     $date_from_file = [datetime]::ParseExact($DateString, $DateFormat ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest
 
Exception setting "CreationTime": "Cannot convert null to type "System.DateTime"."
At C:\Users\Bob\Desktop\Script\test.ps1:17 char:5
+     $FL_Item.CreationTime = $date_from_file
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Thanks in advance for your help. Best regards

Comment: The error is telling you `parseexact` does not accept those 3 parameters https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact. Looking at the docs, it should accept 2 String parameters the date, and the format so just remove `, $null` from the parameter list

Comment: https://pastebin.com/yYPaafpM, it creates new errors by deleting $null

Comment: Click the edit button under your question and add the new information (code and error) at the end

Comment: done and updated as per your request

Comment: The easiest way to see whats going on with your code is to add `Write-Host` commands - you can use it to output the contents of variables and output messages to figure out where exactly the problem is hiding. Few things i notice: `$Null = $FL_Item.BaseName -match '_\d{14}'` wont work work as `$null` is a special variable in powershell, you cant use it like this. Also where is the variable `$Matches` coming from, you dont appear to have defined it anywhere (is this related to the previous lines problem)? Lastly not sure what  `'=' * 20` is for, it will cause an error once you fix the first 2.